# Rxjs angular2 subject is not invoking subscribe function

Tags: angular, rxjs, jwt, angular2-services

I'm beginner with rxjs and currently have problem with invoking subscribe function. My code is something like this:

Component A:

```
getAllData() {
    this.dataService.getDataA().subscribe(
    data => console.log(data))
}
```

dataService:

```
getDataA() {
    let url = "/services/data";
    return this.getData(url)
}

getData() {
//first without JWT
    let sub = new Subject<Response>();
    this.http.get(param1)
        .subscribe(
            res => sub.next(res)
            err => {
                //401 without JWT so I call authService
                this.authServ.getDataWithToken().subscribe(
                    data => sub.next(data)
                )} 
    return sub.asObservable()
}



getData2() {
    //first without JWT
    let sub = new Subject<Response>();
    this.http.get(param1)
        .subscribe(
            res => sub.next(res)
            err => {
                //401 without JWT so I call authService
                this.authServ.getDataWithToken().subscribe(
                    data => sub.next(data)
                )} 
    return sub.asObservable()
}
```

authService:

```
getDataWithToken() {
    let sub = new Subject<Response>()
    this.getToken().subscribe(
        token=> {
        //reachable just once
            this.http.get(url, new RequestOption(tokenHeader))
            .subscribe(
              data => sub.next(data)
            )
    return sub.asObservable();
}


getToken(url) {
    let sub = new Subject<string>();

    if (this.tokens[url])
        // token is already in memory - console log proves it's reachable
        sub.next(this.tokens[url])
    else {
        // also reachable
        this.http.get(newToken).subscribe(
            (data) => sub.next(data))

    return sub.asObservable()
}
```

The issue is, that when I try to reach two restendpoints with token -> going to auth service, just first one is working without problem and second one is being stuck in authService.getDataWithToken.subscribe and it seems it's waiting for data but nothing is coming. I found a workaround (really dirty one), if I copy function getData in service and from one component I call getData and from other one getData2, it's working.

I know, there is more subscription and that is probably the problem. But can someone explain me why it's happening?

Comment: Please update and tidy your code. Difficult to see what's going on - especially as it's not valid JS, so people would need to guess what's correct. Help on how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I updated my code. Unfortunately I can't provide more details about the code. But this pseudocode simulates exactly my situation

Comment: Psuedocode is very difficult for us to diagnose where your issue is - could you create a plunker example to demonstrate the problem? [here is a template to get started](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to replace your getToken with this code, I suppose you sent the token with the subject before you have a subscription to it

```
getToken(url) {
    let sub = new Subject<string>();
    if (this.tokens[url])
    // token is already in memory - console log proves it's reachable 
    {
        return Observable.of(this.tokens[url])
    } else { // also reachable 
        this.http.get(newToken).subscribe((data) => sub.next(data))
        return sub.asObservable()
    }
}
```

Comment: I can try it, but why it's working for first time and second time it's not subscribed before receiving data?

Comment: The first time is hitting the server ? And the second time tries to use the cache ?

Comment: Cause if that's the case, you already have a subscription to the sub when the http comes back and sub.next notifies the subscription. If the second call takes it from cache you don't have a subscription when you send the token with sub.next(this.tokens[url]) and the other subscription is waiting forever for a response, if you use subject instead of Observable you need to be sure that sub.next is called after sub.subscribe is called to not lose values.

Comment: Also please try to use consistent names when you write code, this one is hard to track.

Comment: Thank you very much Nicu, it's working. I'm sorry for my dirty code example, this is not my code, this should just simulate my situation, but I understand next time I'll write it better.

Comment: Nice then, have a look over rxjs observables docs to understand how to compose them